# Get the actors that are inside a rectangle in libGDX

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm making a level editor and I want to make a drag selection. I need to know what's the best way to get the actors that overlap or are inside a rectangle (the selection).

I did a loop that returns an array with all the actors whose edges are inside the rectangle, but I don't know if comparing all the actors of the stage is the best way.

Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated.

Comment: That check should be so fast mathematically that there's probably no reason to pre-optimize it (you're simply comparing numbers). If you find that you're having optimization problems because of this calculation (perhaps if you have several thousands of actors) you could look into [quadtrees](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374).

Comment: How many actors are we talking about? You are not doing yourself any favors by optimizing if it is not necessary.

Comment: It's supposed that users will be able to add as many actors as they want, but they will not need so many actors I suppose. Thank you!